# LWIP : add support for VLAN taggin

Tags: c, microcontroller, lwip, vlan

I run a LWIP stack version 2.0.2, I can broadcast ENET frames without issue:

```
     status_t status = ENET_DRV_SendFrame(INST_ETHERNET1, 0U, &buff, NULL);
      if(status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
      {
          printf("cannot send eth frame \r\n");
      }
```

Now I have a requirement that I should add VLAN support.

I tried to add the define for VLAN support in the file lwipopts.h

```
#define ETHARP_SUPPORT_VLAN         1
```

But this seems not enough.
any suggestion please.